# Why cant i use the PyNaCl library in python repl.it

Tags: python, discord.py, replit

I'm using repl.it to make a discord.py bot and when I run the repl, it says:

```
Repl.it: Updating package configuration

--> python3 -m poetry install
Installing dependencies from lock file


Package operations: 2 installs, 2 updates, 0 removals

  - Updating attrs (20.1.0 -> 20.3.0)
  - Updating aiohttp (3.6.2 -> 3.6.3)
  - Installing discord.py (1.5.1)
  - Installing discord (1.0.1)
```

and doesnt install the PyNaCl library.

I've tried using the packages tab on repl.it and it says `No packages found` and even tried `pip install PyNaCl` in the shell tab. I've imported it into the `main.py` file too.

How do I get repl.it to install the PyNaCL library?

Comment: "even tried `pip install PyNaCl` in the shell tab" - what was the result of running this command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also using repl.it and here's my solution.

I entered

```
pip install PyNaCl
```

on the shell tab and I made sure it's in the list with

```
pip list
```

(If a new version is available and you upgrade to a new version, make sure you install this again and make sure it's in the list.)

Then used it in the code like this

```
import nacl
```

and put that on top of everything like this

```
1 import discord
2 import nacl
3 import os
  .
  .
  .
```

(If it doesn't work for you, try putting it on another line. If it's on the 1st line, try putting it on the 2nd as I did above.)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
poetry add pynacl
```

and retry it.